# Restart a service in the background using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to restart a service in the background, then monitor the if the service has been restarted. If the service has not started as a while, then the service is to be restarted.

I'm having issues with restarting the service in the background the start-job command does run so thats where i'm most probably going wrong. the restart-service and do command work correctly, just cant get it to run in the background.

```
$a = "Restart-Service -InputObject $(get-service -ComputerName $Server -Name Service)"
start-job -scriptblock {$a}
do {
($Check = (Get-Service -ComputerName $RadSvr -Name IAS).status -eq "Running") }
Until ($check -eq $true)
```

After playing around, I noticed the script ran in the background if i didnt use variables in the Start-Job. so if i changed the start-job to include the IP address of a server

```
start-job -scriptblock { Restart-Service -InputObject $(get-service -ComputerName 10.10.10.10 -Name Service) }
```

anyone know how to make variable work?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can simplify your code a little bit by using process functions

```
$service = Get-Service -Name $servicename -ComputerName $targetcomputer
$service.Stop();
$maxTimeout = "00:03:00"
$service.WaitForStatus('Stopped', $maxTimeout);
# check again the status and eventually perform another action
```

Comment: This would work if i do the same for starting the service too, but it make the script very long and complicated. 
If i can get the start-job to work, or perform the task in the background it will be better

Answer (score 1):

Use `Wait-Job` to wait for the job to complete.

```
$a = "Restart-Service -InputObject $(get-service -ComputerName $Server -Name Service)"
$job = start-job -scriptblock {$a}
Wait-Job $job
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the script working. I needed to add `param` and `-argumentlist` in the `start-job`

```
start-job -scriptblock {param($Server) Restart-Service -InputObject $(get-service -ComputerName $Server -Name Service)} -Argumentlist $Server
```